# Rails simple-captcha validation never works? Even when correct

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling, captcha

I'm trying to implement simple-captcha2 into a form in my app but when I test it with an incorrect captcha, I get a **NoMethodError** in **SubmitsController#create**, **undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass**

gem: https://github.com/pludoni/simple-captcha 
I am using Rails 4

I have implemented simple-captcha2 into my application but I always get an error saying the captcha did not match the image even when it does!
After lots of debugging, I still cannot find out why.
I am sure I have gone through the steps in the gem documentation correctly.

My Submits controller:

```
class SubmitsController < ApplicationController
before_action :captchaa, only: [:create]

def new
  @submit = Submit.new
end

def create
    @submit = Submit.new(submit_params)
    if @submit.save_with_captcha
      redirect_to(:action=>'thanks')
    else
      render('new')
    end
end
...
private
 def captchaa
   if simple_captcha_valid?
   else
     render('new')
   end
 end
end
```

And my form view: (I also get the same error here with @submit.errors)

```
<% if @submit.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @submit.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li>
      <%= msg %>
    <% end %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
...form fields
<%= show_simple_captcha %>
```

My model includes:

```
apply_simple_captcha :message => "The secret Image and code were different", :add_to_base => true
```

And my application controller includes:

```
include SimpleCaptcha::ControllerHelpers
```

Perhaps I am incorrectly adding a validation error to the errors array?
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Much appreciated!

Comment: You haven't included captcha_helper as per the doc. `include SimpleCaptcha::ControllerHelpers`

Comment: My application controller does include SimpleCaptcha::ControllerHelpers. I have added it to the post

Comment: I'm also having this issue but only on Chromium, it works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, You need to add errors from model https://github.com/pludoni/simple-captcha#model-options

```
class Submit < ActiveRecord::Base
  apply_simple_captcha :message => "The secret Image and code were  different", :add_to_base => true
end
```

And your controller's create action should look like,

```
def create
  @submit = Submit.new(submit_params)
  if @submit.save_with_captcha
    redirect_to(:action=>'thanks')
  else
    render('new')
  end
end
```

save_with_captcha? will work like save and will also validate captcha. And if it finds any error code in model will add errors. Check https://github.com/pludoni/simple-captcha#saving-with-captcha for more details. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated! Unfortunately I still get the error with those changes added.